# Notepad - initialize object properties in Table row generator

Tags: palantir-foundry

In the new Notepad app, what is the process for initializing an object's properties in the Table row generator's columns?

I'm trying to create a Notepad document template that dynamically creates tables from specified objects via the Table row generator. I've been able to create a document template, select the `Table row generator`, and select a variable (object) to pass into the table, but I can't figure out how to initialize the object's property values into the table's columns, i.e. replacing `"Column Header"` with the object's titles:

[image]

I have tried naming the template input parameters to `$GENERATOR_OBJECT` but receive an error.
[image]

What is the correct procedure here? I've reviewed the Notepad documentation but have not been successful in identifying the right steps.

[Foundry Notepad Docs](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/notepad/widgets-table-row-generator/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs have not fully caught up with the latest changes on Notepad yet. Sorry about that.

To connect an embedded section's input parameter with its surrounding Section or Table Row Generator, you need to set the parameter to `$GENERATOR_OBJECT`. This parameter will be automatically selectable for widgets **inside** generators that accept object template inputs.

Your table has two rows: a normal one (pre-filled with `Column Header`) and a generator row below (recognizable by the blue dashed line). The `$GENERATOR_OBJECT` parameter will only be automatically available in the generator row.

The figure below shows an example for an [Object Property](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/notepad/widgets-object-property/) inside a table row generator.

[image: Figure: Connect Object Property to Row Generator]

Comment: Is there a special process to name a parameter as $GENERATOR_OBJECT? I am unable to and receive the error "$GENERATOR_OBJECT is a reserved name." We are extremely excited for Notepad.

Comment: The "$GENERATOR_OBJECT" will be automatically available for widgets inside generators that accept object template inputs.
I updated my answer to clarify and added a better screenshot.

Comment: Understand. Since I'm unable to set the $GENERATOR_OBJECT parameter name after following the above, I suspect the latest updates haven't hit our stack yet.

Comment: Follow-up: The NotePad Templates/generator rows now work as expected for us, after reviewing the above. Awesome!